# How can I connect remote mysql db from my local?

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to connect to the remote mysql db from my local XAMPP php, it says,

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host
'testhost.testserver.com' (11004) in D:\xampp\htdocs\cvsprojects\test\initdb.php 
on line 24
```

I am sure the mysql host, user name , password are correct to connect.

Comment: Are you sure your can actually reach the box? Try pinging `testhost.testserver.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remote MySQL server must allow remote clients to connect. I Am quoting this from a web page

> you need to have remote access privileges to the MySQL server. You must use your client IP address or a %-wildcard in the Host column of the mysql.user table next to your username. For more information on connecting to a remote MySQL server see the MySQL documentation (Security and GRANT topics).

Moreover, make sure your system can access the network your remote server is hosted on. After that its plain simple connection settings or strings as some call it.

Comment: it would tell him "this server is not allowed", ..... It's not my downvote, though

Comment: I realised it and added more details, downvotes do not scare me now, I have seen people with super duper repo asking question which google can answer easily :-)

Comment: @Kumar They are still valid questions.

Comment: @NullUserException yes they are, but I wonder why not find an answer using google and learn by doing rather than asking all the questions on SO. Its my POV, no offence to anyone.